# 'Expression' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Tags: python, datetime, peewee

I try get data with creation time more 60 mins. But its show error. How correct substract data?

```
hour = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 60)
zayavkis =Zayavki.select().where(Zayavki.req_data-hour).seconds/60>60)
```

Comment: The code has more closing than opening parentheses. It cannot be valid.

Comment: If you are posting to SO, please do not also open issues on the peewee issue tracker for questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing your model definition, e.g. what kind of field is `Zayavki.req_data`? But here are some ideas:

```py
# option 1 (reference time from python)
one_hour_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)  # or `hours=1`?
zayavkis = Zayavki.select().where(Zayavki.req_data < one_hour_ago)


# option 2 (reference time from db)
zayavkis = Zayavki.select().where(Zayavki.req_data < fn.DATE_SUB(fn.NOW(), SQL('INTERVAL 1 HOUR')))
```

Also, be careful with timezones. You should ideally use UTC everywhere, and then you'll want to use `utcnow()` instead of `now()`